# How to create multiple frames in python through For Loop?

Tags: python

I am working on GUI programming of python using Tkinter.
I am creating 4 frames(Frame1, Frame2, Frame3 and Frame4) in my Tkinter Root Window by using the below code:

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tki.Tk()        
        self.root.wm_title("Play With python")
        for r in range(8):
            self.root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(2):
            self.root.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
    # Create Frames
        Frame1 = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
        Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s')

        Frame2 = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
        Frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s')

        Frame3 = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
        Frame3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s')

        Frame4 = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
        Frame4.grid(row = 6, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s')

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

The same thing I want to do using a **for loop** to make my code readable as in my real code the frames are around 12.

I am trying the below code for the same output:

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tki.Tk()        
        self.root.wm_title("Play With python")
        for r in range(8):
            self.root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(2):
            self.root.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
    # Create Frames
        j = 0
        for i in range(1,5):
            Framei = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
            Framei.grid(row = j, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s') 
            j = j + 2
app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

**Problem:**

As I can see the problem this code is creating 4 frames but with same name reference as **Framei**(and not as Frame1, Frame2, Frame3 and Frame4). 
But I want 4 separate frames with different names as (Frame1, Frame2, Frame3 and Frame4).

I know my problem is quite related to **variable creation at Run Time**, but as I am applying it first time So facing Problem.

Python Version I am using is 3.0.1.
Please Help...

Comment: you should mark the answer as correct (click the tick mark).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should place the `Frame` instances in a list like so:

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tki.Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Play With python")
        for r in range(8):
            self.root.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        for c in range(2):
            self.root.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        # Create a list of the Frames in the order they were created
        frames = []
        j = 0
        for i in range(1,5):
            Frame = tki.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, bg = 'blue')
            Frame.grid(row = j, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'w, e, n, s')

            # Add the Frame to the list
            frames.append(Frame)

            # Also, just as an FYI, j = j + 2 can be better written like this
            j += 2

        # To demonstrate
        print(frames)

        # This is the first Frame created
        print(frames[0])

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

To access the Frames, just index the list.

Comment: Thank you iCodez for your answer. My Problem is solved and concept is also clear now. The same thing if we do in other Programming Languages(say C) then we will use the Concept of Array there. Thanks

Comment: @AshA: Glad I could help.  However, if you feel that my answer solved your problem appropriately, then you should accept it to keep SO clean and organized.  If not, I'll be glad to help further.

Comment: Yes, with your answer my problem was solved and I am 90% Done with my work. Can You suggest any Reading to Explore more about GUI Programming in Python??

Comment: @Asha: Yes, I suppose I have a few good things:  http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html         http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/       These are what I myself use (besides SO of course) to solve my problems.

Comment: Thanks ICodez, Links are really helpful as I was puzzled reading "docs.python.org" library, but di did not get more from there related to GUI. Thanks

Comment: The print statements really help illustrate that the frames are their own objects. That was a big ah-hah moment for me. Calling that out.